# If we know that $P^2=P$, show that $(I+P)^{-1}=I-\frac{1}{2}P$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, idempotents

the problem is as follows. given that P is a matrix with the property $P^2=P$ show that $(I+P)^{-1}=I-\frac{1}{2}P$.
I tried squaring both quantities and using the fact that I can interchange the exponents on the RHS but it did not yield anything helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $(I+P)(I-\tfrac12P)=I+\tfrac12P-\tfrac12P^2=I$, $(I+P)^{-1}=I-\tfrac12P$.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, so we can just multiply the quantities to check if we get the identity matrix, if so it implies that they must be one another's inverse. I never thought about that, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$(I+P)(I-\frac{1}{2}P) = I - \frac{1}{2}P + P - \frac{1}{2}P^2 = I - \frac{1}{2}P + P - \frac{1}{2}P = I$.

Thus $I-\frac{1}{2}P$ is an inverse of $I+P$. But the inverse is uniquely determined and therefore $(I+P)^{-1} = I-\frac{1}{2}P$.

Comment: I see now that I overcomplicated the problem immensely, I thought that based on the information that P^2=P I should for some reason try and square it and do some magic but just like you have shown, I only needed to show that the two quantities multiplied yields the identity matrix because that would then imply they are one another's inverse Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you have a candidate matrix that you'd like to show is the inverse of $(I+P)$, simply multiply it by $(I+P)$ and verify that you get the identity matrix $I$.

Try it yourself, then click to reveal the calculation:

> ! $$
> \begin{align*}
> (I - \tfrac{1}{2}P) (I + P) 
> &= I + P - \tfrac{1}{2}P - \tfrac{1}{2}\color{red}{P^2} \\
> &= I + P - \tfrac{1}{2}P - \tfrac{1}{2}\color{red}{P} = I
> \end{align*}
> $$

Comment: Yes, it worked wonders, my biggest issue was not realizing I could just multiply them together and check if it would yield back the identity matrix. Since AA^(-1)=I and A(-1)A=I as well. Thanks!